# Centroidal Voronoi tesselations around obstacles

Tags: python, computational-geometry, voronoi, delaunay, scipy-spatial

I am trying to implement a Centroidal Voronoi tessellation algorithm in a bounded rectangular space such that, the bounding rectangle has a number of obstacles(polygons) in it.

The below code gives the centroidal voronoi tessellations in a bounding box without the presence of obstacles(polygons). The blue points are the generators, red points the centroids and yellow points are the in between points between the blue and red points. [image: Voronoi without obstacles]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.spatial
import sys


np.random.seed(1)
eps = sys.float_info.epsilon

n_robots = 10
robots = np.random.rand(n_robots, 2)
#print(robots)
bounding_box = np.array([0., 1., 0., 1.]) 

def in_box(robots, bounding_box):
    return np.logical_and(np.logical_and(bounding_box[0] <= robots[:, 0],
                                         robots[:, 0] <= bounding_box[1]),
                          np.logical_and(bounding_box[2] <= robots[:, 1],
                                         robots[:, 1] <= bounding_box[3]))



def voronoi(robots, bounding_box):
    i = in_box(robots, bounding_box)
    points_center = robots[i, :]
    points_left = np.copy(points_center)
    points_left[:, 0] = bounding_box[0] - (points_left[:, 0] - bounding_box[0])
    points_right = np.copy(points_center)
    points_right[:, 0] = bounding_box[1] + (bounding_box[1] - points_right[:, 0])
    points_down = np.copy(points_center)
    points_down[:, 1] = bounding_box[2] - (points_down[:, 1] - bounding_box[2])
    points_up = np.copy(points_center)
    points_up[:, 1] = bounding_box[3] + (bounding_box[3] - points_up[:, 1])
    points = np.append(points_center,
                       np.append(np.append(points_left,
                                           points_right,
                                           axis=0),
                                 np.append(points_down,
                                           points_up,
                                           axis=0),
                                 axis=0),
                       axis=0)
# Compute Voronoi
    vor = sp.spatial.Voronoi(points)
    # Filter regions and select corresponding points
    regions = []
    points_to_filter = [] # we'll need to gather points too
    ind = np.arange(points.shape[0])
    ind = np.expand_dims(ind,axis= 1)

    for i,region in enumerate(vor.regions): # enumerate the regions
        if not region: # nicer to skip the empty region altogether
            continue

        flag = True
        for index in region:
            if index == -1:
                flag = False
                break
            else:
                x = vor.vertices[index, 0]
                y = vor.vertices[index, 1]
                if not(bounding_box[0] - eps <= x and x <= bounding_box[1] + eps and
                      bounding_box[2] - eps <= y and y <= bounding_box[3] + eps):
                    flag = False
                    break
        if flag:
            regions.append(region)

           # find the point which lies inside
            points_to_filter.append(vor.points[vor.point_region == i][0,:])

    vor.filtered_points = np.array(points_to_filter)
    vor.filtered_regions = regions
    return vor

def centroid_region(vertices):

    A = 0

    C_x = 0

    C_y = 0
    for i in range(0, len(vertices) - 1):
        s = (vertices[i, 0] * vertices[i + 1, 1] - vertices[i + 1, 0] * vertices[i, 1])
        A = A + s
        C_x = C_x + (vertices[i, 0] + vertices[i + 1, 0]) * s
        C_y = C_y + (vertices[i, 1] + vertices[i + 1, 1]) * s
    A = 0.5 * A
    C_x = (1.0 / (6.0 * A)) * C_x
    C_y = (1.0 / (6.0 * A)) * C_y
    return np.array([[C_x, C_y]])

def plot(r,index):
    vor = voronoi(r, bounding_box)

    fig = pl.figure()
    ax = fig.gca()
    #ax.plot(pol2[:,0],pol2[:,1],'k-')
# Plot initial points
    ax.plot(vor.filtered_points[:, 0], vor.filtered_points[:, 1], 'b.')
    print("initial",vor.filtered_points)
# Plot ridges points
    for region in vor.filtered_regions:
        vertices = vor.vertices[region, :]
        ax.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], 'go')
# Plot ridges
    for region in vor.filtered_regions:
        vertices = vor.vertices[region + [region[0]], :]
        ax.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], 'k-')
# Compute and plot centroids
    centroids = []
    for region in vor.filtered_regions:
        vertices = vor.vertices[region + [region[0]], :]
        centroid = centroid_region(vertices)
        centroids.append(list(centroid[0, :]))
        ax.plot(centroid[:, 0], centroid[:, 1], 'r.')
    centroids = np.asarray(centroids)
    rob = np.copy(vor.filtered_points)
    # the below code is for the plotting purpose the update happens in the update function
    interim_x = np.asarray(centroids[:,0] - rob[:,0])
    interim_y = np.asarray(centroids[:,1] - rob[:,1])
    magn = [np.linalg.norm(centroids[i,:] - rob[i,:]) for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
    x = np.copy(interim_x)
    x = np.asarray([interim_x[i]/magn[i] for i in range(interim_x.shape[0])])
    y = np.copy(interim_y)
    y = np.asarray([interim_y[i]/magn[i] for i in range(interim_y.shape[0])])
    nor = np.copy(rob)
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        nor[i,0] = x[i]
        nor[i,1] = y[i]
    temp = np.copy(rob)
    temp[:,0] = [rob[i,0] + 0.5*interim_x[i] for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
    temp[:,1] = [rob[i,1] + 0.5*interim_y[i] for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
    pol = [[]]
    ax.plot(temp[:,0] ,temp[:,1], 'y.' )
    ax.set_xlim([-0.1, 1.1])
    ax.set_ylim([-0.1, 1.1])
    pl.savefig("voronoi" + str(index) + ".png")
    return centroids

def update(rob,centroids):

  interim_x = np.asarray(centroids[:,0] - rob[:,0])
  interim_y = np.asarray(centroids[:,1] - rob[:,1])
  magn = [np.linalg.norm(centroids[i,:] - rob[i,:]) for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
  x = np.copy(interim_x)
  x = np.asarray([interim_x[i]/magn[i] for i in range(interim_x.shape[0])])
  y = np.copy(interim_y)
  y = np.asarray([interim_y[i]/magn[i] for i in range(interim_y.shape[0])])
  nor = [np.linalg.norm([x[i],y[i]]) for i in range(x.shape[0])]
  temp = np.copy(rob)
  temp[:,0] = [rob[i,0] + 0.5*interim_x[i] for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
  temp[:,1] = [rob[i,1] + 0.5*interim_y[i] for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
  return np.asarray(temp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1):
        centroids = plot(robots,i)
        robots = update(robots,centroids)
```

Now I want to extend this particular code to the case with obstacles i.e I want to do something like [image: this] except I don't want anything in the red polygons.

One approach I tried was to partition the space using the free area which did not go well. [image].

Code for approach one :

```
import random
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def get_random_point_in_polygon(poly,polygons,num):
     (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) = poly.bounds
     points =[]
     while num != 0:
         p = Point(random.uniform(minx, maxx), random.uniform(miny, maxy))
         if any(poly.contains(p) for poly in polygons):
             continue
         else:
            num = num-1
            #print(num)
            points.append([p.x,p.y])
     return np.asarray(points)

def polysplit(poly,polygons):
     (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) = poly.bounds
     pols =[]

     return pols

def randomRects(p,poly):
    (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) = poly.bounds
    rect = []
    while True:
        w = round(random.uniform(0, 1),3)
        h = round(random.uniform(0, 1),3)

        if (((p[:,0]+w) < maxx) and ((p[:,1]+h) < maxy)):
            rect.append(np.squeeze([np.squeeze(p[:,0]),np.squeeze(p[:,1])]))
            rect.append(np.squeeze([np.squeeze(p[:,0]+w),np.squeeze(p[:,1])]))
            rect.append(np.squeeze([np.squeeze(p[:,0]+w),np.squeeze(p[:,1]+h)]))
            rect.append(np.squeeze([np.squeeze(p[:,0]),np.squeeze(p[:,1]+h)]))
            rect.append(np.squeeze([np.squeeze(p[:,0]),np.squeeze(p[:,1])]))


            break
        else:
            continue
    return np.asarray(rect)


def rect(poly,polygons):
    rec =[]
    area = poly.area
    areas = 0
    for i in polygons:
        areas = areas+i.area
    #print(area - areas)
    flag = False
    while (area - areas) > 0.4:
        p = get_random_point_in_polygon(poly,polygons,1)
        #print(p)
        rect = randomRects(p,poly)
        if any(poly.intersects(Polygon(rect)) for poly in polygons):

            continue
        #elif any(poly.intersects(Polygon(rect)) for poly in rec):
            #continue
        else:
            if rec == []:
                rec.append(Polygon(rect))
                print("hi")
            elif any(pol.intersects(Polygon(rect)) for pol in rec):
                continue
            else:
                areas = areas+Polygon(rect).area
                print(area-areas)
                rec.append(Polygon(rect))
    return rec
p = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)])
p2 = Polygon([(0, 0), (.2,0), (.2,.2), (0, 0.2), (0,0)])
p3 = Polygon([(0.4, 0.4), (0.8,0.4), (.8,.8), (0.4, 0.8), (0.4,0.4)])
p4 = Polygon([(0.1,0.6),(0.3,.6),(0.3,0.9),(0.1,0.9),(0.1,0.6)])
p5 = Polygon([(0.25,0.25),(0.85,.25),(0.85,0.35),(0.25,0.35),(0.25,0.25)])
polygons = []
polygons.append(p2)
polygons.append(p3)
polygons.append(p4)
polygons.append(p5)
point_in_poly = get_random_point_in_polygon(p,polygons,10000)
fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
#ax.plot(point_in_poly[:,0],point_in_poly[:,1],'b.')
area = 0
for po in polygons:
    #area = area +po.area

    x,y = po.exterior.xy
    #print [x,y]
    ax.plot(x,y,'r-')
#print(p.area - area)
r = rect(p,polygons)
for rr in r:
    #area = area +po.area

    x,y = rr.exterior.xy
    #print [x,y]
    ax.plot(x,y,'b-')


ax.set_xlim([-0.1, 1.1])
ax.set_ylim([-0.1, 1.1])
pl.savefig("test1.png")
```

Second approach i thought to use binary space partitioning to divide the free area into rectangles and apply the above code to each of these free area rectangles. But I am not sure how to do this in a python.

Third approach : I used the Python triangle library to calculate the conforming  constrained delaunay triangulation of the free space and tried porting it back to a voronoi diagram. The results were not as expected.
[image: CCDT of a test case] and it's [image: it's corresponding voronoi diagram]

The code below is a compilation of all the methods i tried so it might be messy. I tried using the Voronoi function in Scipy,Triangle libraries and also a tried converting the triangulation to voronoi using a custom approach. The code doesn't work well and also has some errors .

```
from numpy import array
import numpy as np


def read_poly(file_name):
    """
    Simple poly-file reader, that creates a python dictionary 
    with information about vertices, edges and holes.
    It assumes that vertices have no attributes or boundary markers.
    It assumes that edges have no boundary markers.
    No regional attributes or area constraints are parsed.
    """

    output = {'vertices': None, 'holes': None, 'segments': None}

    # open file and store lines in a list
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    lines = [x.strip('\n').split() for x in lines]

    # Store vertices
    vertices= []
    N_vertices, dimension, attr, bdry_markers = [int(x) for x in lines[0]]
    # We assume attr = bdrt_markers = 0
    for k in range(N_vertices):
        label, x, y = [items for items in lines[k+1]]
        vertices.append([float(x), float(y)])
    output['vertices']=array(vertices)

    # Store segments
    segments = []
    N_segments, bdry_markers = [int(x) for x in lines[N_vertices+1]]
    for k in range(N_segments):
        label, pointer_1, pointer_2 = [items for items in lines[N_vertices+k+2]]
        segments.append([int(pointer_1)-1, int(pointer_2)-1])
    output['segments'] = array(segments)

    # Store holes
    N_holes = int(lines[N_segments+N_vertices+2][0])
    holes = []
    for k in range(N_holes):
        label, x, y = [items for items in lines[N_segments + N_vertices + 3 + k]]
        holes.append([float(x), float(y)])

    output['holes'] = array(holes)
    print(holes)

    return output


from triangle import triangulate,voronoi, plot as tplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = read_poly("/home/pranav/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/test.poly")
cncfq20adt = triangulate(image, 'pq20a.01D')
#print(cncfq20adt['vertices'])
#print(cncfq20adt['triangles'])
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
tplot.plot(ax, **cncfq20adt)
plt.savefig("image.png")


import triangle
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

pts = cncfq20adt['vertices']
tri = Delaunay(pts)
p = tri.points[tri.vertices]

#print(pts)
# Triangle vertices
A = p[:,0,:].T
B = p[:,1,:].T
C = p[:,2,:].T
print(C)
# See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Circumscribed_circles_of_triangles
# The following is just a direct transcription of the formula there
a = A - C
b = B - C

def dot2(u, v):
    return u[0]*v[0] + u[1]*v[1]

def cross2(u, v, w):
    """u x (v x w)"""
    return dot2(u, w)*v - dot2(u, v)*w

def ncross2(u, v):
    """|| u x v ||^2"""
    return sq2(u)*sq2(v) - dot2(u, v)**2

def sq2(u):
    return dot2(u, u)

cc = cross2(sq2(a) * b - sq2(b) * a, a, b) / (2*ncross2(a, b)) + C

# Grab the Voronoi edges
vc = cc[:,tri.neighbors]
vc[:,tri.neighbors == -1] = np.nan # edges at infinity, plotting those would need more work...

lines = []
lines.extend(zip(cc.T, vc[:,:,0].T))
lines.extend(zip(cc.T, vc[:,:,1].T))
lines.extend(zip(cc.T, vc[:,:,2].T))

# Plot it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

lines = LineCollection(lines, edgecolor='b')

#plt.hold(1)
plt.plot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], '.')
plt.plot(cc[0], cc[1], '*')
plt.gca().add_collection(lines)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(-0.1, 1.1)
plt.ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
plt.savefig("vor2.png")
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')
triangle.plot.plot(ax1, vertices=pts)
lim = ax1.axis()

points, edges, ray_origin, ray_direct = triangle.voronoi(pts)
d = dict(vertices=points, edges=edges, ray_origins=ray_origin, ray_directions=ray_direct)
ax2 = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
triangle.plot.plot(ax2, **d)
ax2.axis(lim)

plt.savefig("vor.png")


import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

import scipy as sp
import scipy.spatial
import sys
from shapely.geometry import Polygon,Point
import random
np.random.seed(1)
eps = sys.float_info.epsilon
"""
n_robots = 50
#robots = np.random.rand(n_robots, 2) 

def get_random_point_in_polygon(poly,polygons,num):
     (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) = poly.bounds
     points =[]
     while num != 0:
         p = Point(random.uniform(minx, maxx), random.uniform(miny, maxy))
         if any(poly.contains(p) for poly in polygons):
             continue
         else:
          num = num-1
          print(num)
          points.append([p.x,p.y])
     return np.asarray(points)

def polysplit(poly,polygons):
    rectangles = []

    return rectangles
p = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)])
p2 = Polygon([(0, 0), (.2,0), (.2,.2), (0, 0.2), (0,0)])
p3 = Polygon([(0.4, 0.4), (0.7,0.4), (.7,.7), (0.4, 0.7), (0.4,0.4)])
polygons = []
polygons.append(p2)
polygons.append(p3)
#point_in_poly = get_random_point_in_polygon(p,polygons,10)
robots = get_random_point_in_polygon(p,polygons,n_robots)

#print(sampl)
print(robots)
bounding_box = np.array([0., 1, 0., 1]) 
box = np.array([0.2, 0.6, 0, 0.6])
box2 = np.array([0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6])
boxes =[]
boxes.append(box)
boxes.append(box2)
"""
robots = cncfq20adt['vertices']
print("length",len(robots))
bounding_box = np.array([0., 1., 0., 1.])

def in_box(robots, bounding_box):
    return np.logical_and(np.logical_and(bounding_box[0] <= robots[:, 0],
                                         robots[:, 0] <= bounding_box[1]),
                          np.logical_and(bounding_box[2] <= robots[:, 1],
                                         robots[:, 1] <= bounding_box[3]))



def voronoi(robots, bounding_box):
    i = in_box(robots, bounding_box)
    points_center = robots[i, :]
    points_left = np.copy(points_center)
    points_left[:, 0] = bounding_box[0] - (points_left[:, 0] - bounding_box[0])
    points_right = np.copy(points_center)
    points_right[:, 0] = bounding_box[1] + (bounding_box[1] - points_right[:, 0])
    points_down = np.copy(points_center)
    points_down[:, 1] = bounding_box[2] - (points_down[:, 1] - bounding_box[2])
    points_up = np.copy(points_center)
    points_up[:, 1] = bounding_box[3] + (bounding_box[3] - points_up[:, 1])
    points = np.append(points_center,
                       np.append(np.append(points_left,
                                           points_right,
                                           axis=0),
                                 np.append(points_down,
                                           points_up,
                                           axis=0),
                                 axis=0),
                       axis=0)
# Compute Voronoi
    vor = sp.spatial.Voronoi(points)
    # Filter regions and select corresponding points
    regions = []
    points_to_filter = [] # we'll need to gather points too
    ind = np.arange(points.shape[0])
    ind = np.expand_dims(ind,axis= 1)

    for i,region in enumerate(vor.regions): # enumerate the regions
        if not region: # nicer to skip the empty region altogether
            continue

        flag = True
        for index in region:
            if index == -1:
                flag = False
                break
            else:
                x = vor.vertices[index, 0]
                y = vor.vertices[index, 1]
                if not(bounding_box[0] - eps <= x and x <= bounding_box[1] + eps and
                      bounding_box[2] - eps <= y and y <= bounding_box[3] + eps):
                    flag = False
                    break
        if flag:
            regions.append(region)

           # find the point which lies inside
            points_to_filter.append(vor.points[vor.point_region == i][0,:])

    vor.filtered_points = np.array(points_to_filter)
    vor.filtered_regions = regions
    return vor

def centroid_region(vertices):

    A = 0

    C_x = 0

    C_y = 0
    for i in range(0, len(vertices) - 1):
        s = (vertices[i, 0] * vertices[i + 1, 1] - vertices[i + 1, 0] * vertices[i, 1])
        A = A + s
        C_x = C_x + (vertices[i, 0] + vertices[i + 1, 0]) * s
        C_y = C_y + (vertices[i, 1] + vertices[i + 1, 1]) * s
    A = 0.5 * A
    C_x = (1.0 / (6.0 * A)) * C_x
    C_y = (1.0 / (6.0 * A)) * C_y
    return np.array([[C_x, C_y]])

def plot(r,index):
    vor = voronoi(r, bounding_box)

    fig = pl.figure()
    ax = fig.gca()
    #ax.plot(pol2[:,0],pol2[:,1],'k-')
# Plot initial points
    ax.plot(vor.filtered_points[:, 0], vor.filtered_points[:, 1], 'b.')
    print("initial",vor.filtered_points)
# Plot ridges points
    for region in vor.filtered_regions:
        vertices = vor.vertices[region, :]
        ax.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], 'go')
# Plot ridges
    for region in vor.filtered_regions:
        vertices = vor.vertices[region + [region[0]], :]
        ax.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], 'k-')
# Compute and plot centroids
    centroids = []
    for region in vor.filtered_regions:
        vertices = vor.vertices[region + [region[0]], :]
        centroid = centroid_region(vertices)
        centroids.append(list(centroid[0, :]))
        ax.plot(centroid[:, 0], centroid[:, 1], 'r.')
    centroids = np.asarray(centroids)
    rob = np.copy(vor.filtered_points)
    # the below code is for the plotting purpose the update happens in the update function
    interim_x = np.asarray(centroids[:,0] - rob[:,0])
    interim_y = np.asarray(centroids[:,1] - rob[:,1])
    magn = [np.linalg.norm(centroids[i,:] - rob[i,:]) for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
    x = np.copy(interim_x)
    x = np.asarray([interim_x[i]/magn[i] for i in range(interim_x.shape[0])])
    y = np.copy(interim_y)
    y = np.asarray([interim_y[i]/magn[i] for i in range(interim_y.shape[0])])
    nor = np.copy(rob)
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        nor[i,0] = x[i]
        nor[i,1] = y[i]
    temp = np.copy(rob)
    temp[:,0] = [rob[i,0] + 0.5*interim_x[i] for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
    temp[:,1] = [rob[i,1] + 0.5*interim_y[i] for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
    pol = [[]]
    ax.plot(temp[:,0] ,temp[:,1], 'y.' )
    ax.set_xlim([-0.1, 1.1])
    ax.set_ylim([-0.1, 1.1])
    pl.savefig("voronoi" + str(index) + ".png")
    return centroids

def update(rob,centroids):

  interim_x = np.asarray(centroids[:,0] - rob[:,0])
  interim_y = np.asarray(centroids[:,1] - rob[:,1])
  magn = [np.linalg.norm(centroids[i,:] - rob[i,:]) for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
  x = np.copy(interim_x)
  x = np.asarray([interim_x[i]/magn[i] for i in range(interim_x.shape[0])])
  y = np.copy(interim_y)
  y = np.asarray([interim_y[i]/magn[i] for i in range(interim_y.shape[0])])
  nor = [np.linalg.norm([x[i],y[i]]) for i in range(x.shape[0])]
  temp = np.copy(rob)
  temp[:,0] = [rob[i,0] + 0.5*interim_x[i] for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
  temp[:,1] = [rob[i,1] + 0.5*interim_y[i] for i in range(rob.shape[0])]
  return np.asarray(temp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1):
        centroids = plot(robots,i)
        robots = update(robots,centroids)
```

I will be really really grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: 16 2 0 0
1  0 0
2  0.5 0
3  1 0
4  1 0.5
5  1 1 
6  0.5 1
7  0 1
8  0 0.5
9  0.25 0.25
10  0.5 0.25
11  0.5 0.5
12  0.25 0.5
13  0.7 0.7
14  0.9 0.7
15  0.9 0.9
16  0.7 0.9
16 0
1  1 2
2  2 3
3  3 4
4  4 5
5  5 6
6  6 7
7  7 8
8  8 1
9  9 10
10 10 11
11 11 12
12 12 9
13 13 14
14 14 15
15 15 16
16 16 13
2
1  0.85 0.85
2 0.35 0.35

Comment: I posted the poly file in the comment above

Comment: If you've solved this issue, please post an answer here and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution to this, and found that several very clever people had done most of the work for me! There is a useful package called geovoronoi, that performs voronoi calculations on constrained spaces via shapely polygons, and then these can be plotted using code from: https://sgillies.net/2010/04/06/painting-punctured-polygons-with-matplotlib.html.

I put together the following code, which should help

```
from geovoronoi import voronoi_regions_from_coords

import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon, Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon as mPolygon
from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.path import Path


def RingCoding(ob):
    # The codes will be all "LINETO" commands, except for "MOVETO"s at the
    # beginning of each subpath
    n = len(ob.coords)
    codes = np.ones(n, dtype=Path.code_type) * Path.LINETO
    codes[0] = Path.MOVETO
    return codes

def Pathify(polygon):
    # Convert coordinates to path vertices. Objects produced by Shapely's
    # analytic methods have the proper coordinate order, no need to sort.
    vertices = np.concatenate(
                    [np.asarray(polygon.exterior)]
                    + [np.asarray(r) for r in polygon.interiors])
    codes = np.concatenate(
                [RingCoding(polygon.exterior)]
                + [RingCoding(r) for r in polygon.interiors])
    return Path(vertices, codes)

def CreatePatch(poly,area_override=None):
    MAX_DENSITY = 0.75
    area = poly.area
    if area_override is not None:
        area=area_override
    density = 1 / area
    color = (min(1, density / MAX_DENSITY), max(0, (MAX_DENSITY - density) / MAX_DENSITY), 0, 0.5)
    region_external_coords = list(poly.exterior.coords)

    if len(poly.interiors) > 0:
        path = Pathify(poly)
        patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor=color, edgecolor=color)
    else:
        patch = mPolygon(region_external_coords, True)
    patch.set_color(color)
    return patch

def main():
    coords = np.array([[-29, 4], [-6, 3], [-1, -1], [-1.5, 0], [-9, -2],
                       [0, 0], [-1, 0], [3, 7], [3.2, 6.8],
                       [3.5, 7.2], [0.1, 2], [-3, 3],
                        [10, 10], [7, 15]
                       ])

    #DEFINE EXTERIOR POLYGONS HERE
    a = [(-40, -4), (-40, 6), (2,6), (2, -4), (-40, -4)]
    b = [(2, 6), (14, 6), (14, 19), (2, 19), (2, 6)]

    #DEFINE INTERNAL HOLES HERE
    hole_a_1 = LinearRing([(-20,-2), (-25,-2), (-25, 2),(-20, 2), (-20, -2)])
    hole_a_2 = LinearRing([(-30, -2), (-35, -2), (-35, 2), (-30, 2), (-30, -2)])
    hole_a_3 = LinearRing([(-20, 4.9), (-10, 4.9), (-10, 2), (-20, 4.9),])

    shapely_poly = MultiPolygon([[a, [hole_a_1, hole_a_2, hole_a_3]], [b,[]]])

    min_x, min_y = np.inf, np.inf
    max_x, max_y = -np.inf, -np.inf
    for poly in shapely_poly:
        bounds=poly.bounds
        min_x=min(bounds[0], min_x)
        max_x=max(bounds[2], max_x)
        min_y=min(bounds[1], min_y)
        max_y=max(bounds[3], max_y)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(min_x-5, max_x+5)
    ax.set_ylim(min_y-5, max_y+5)

    # this creates a dictionary of polygons/multipolygons
    # and a dictionary of lists, indicating which point is in those polygons
    # (if there are identical points, those lists might have 2+ numbers in them)
    region_polys, region_pts = voronoi_regions_from_coords(coords, shapely_poly)

    for i in region_polys:
        if type(region_polys[i]) is MultiPolygon:
            # this means that the voronoi cell is technically a multipolygon.
            # while you could argue whether this should ever occur, the current implementation
            # does this.
            # so, we should probably check which polygon actually contains the point.
            point=region_pts[i][0]
            temp_point=Point(coords[point])
            for poly in region_polys[i]:
                if poly.contains(temp_point):
                    #this is the one.
                    patch=CreatePatch(poly)
                    ax.add_patch(patch)
                    temp_area=poly.area
            for poly in region_polys[i]:
                if not poly.contains(temp_point):
                    patch=CreatePatch(poly, temp_area)
                    ax.add_patch(patch)

        else:
            patch=CreatePatch(region_polys[i])
            ax.add_patch(patch)

    points=list(zip(*coords))
    plt.scatter(points[0], points[1])
    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDTVF.png)